# Why jQuery needs Sizzle internally?

Tags: jquery, css, sizzle

When I was looking at the jQuery code source, I became interested in [Sizzle-js](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle), which is a CSS selector engine library that jQuery uses for selecting DOM elements. So, my question is why jQuery includes an entire library for just selecting DOM elements? What features introduce Sizzle that let's jQuery uses it internally?

In order to answer on this I do some researches on [Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle) and his features, the main function of Sizzle is `Sizzle(selector)`, this function returns an array-like object that contains some methods that allow you to operate on the DOM elements you've isolated, and this is very helpful actually if your application touched the DOM frequently.  But, in my opinion, this isn't worth to include a [20KB](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sizzle/2.3.5/sizzle.min.js) of code, I know that [Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle) covered also the old browser versions that don't support the [`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function, but I'm still not convinced!

Actually, you can do what Sizzle do (Simulate the concept) in few lines of code, I've written a very simple example based on `querySelectorAll`:

```js
var Select = function(selector) {
    if (typeof selector !== 'string') throw 'selector must be of type string';

    var client = function() {
        var eles = document.querySelectorAll(selector), i = eles.length;

        this.length = eles.length;

        while(i--) {
            this[i] = eles[i];
        }
    };

    client.prototype = Array.prototype;

    return new client();
};

console.log(Sizzle('div').includes(document.querySelector('div'))); // true
console.log(Select('div').includes(document.querySelector('div'))); // true

var divs = Select('div'); 

divs.forEach(function(div) {
    div.textContent = 'Changed!!';     
});
```

So why jQuery still uses Sizzle? the `document.querySelectorAll` and `document.querySelector` are now available in modern browsers, why jQuery still depends on Sizzle on this?

Note: There is an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762887/how-and-what-benefit-can-i-take-by-including-sizzle-js-along-with-jquery1-4-2) that is similar to this one, however, I'm not satisfied with the answers since it focuses more on *What is Sizzle JS, and what can do ?*, rather than *why jQuery uses Sizzle?*.

I hope my question was clear and sorry for my bad English, thanks.

Comment: Bottom answer of this may help ya https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685782/what-is-the-difference-between-sizzle-and-document-queryselectorall

Comment: @Canvas good question, thanks!!

Comment: The history goes like that: Javascript was hated. Javascript got adopted. Javascript was hard. Lots of libraries were introduced. jQuery/Sizzle made everything easy. jQuery was the winner. Some jQuery developers went to Google. Javascript adopted parts of jQuery like "querySelector". jQuery is legacy now. "RIP" jQuery. I loved you.

Comment: jQuery predates `document.querySelectorAll()` by many years.

Comment: @Barmar, yes you're right. but why it still uses Sizzle even though the `document.querySelectorAll` was introduced after and it widely supported now, why jQuery not moved to use the native `querySelectorAll` until this time?

Comment: jQuery has a number of extensions to selector syntax. Did it get them from Sizzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's selector syntax includes a number of extensions to CSS selectors, such as `:input` and `:selected`. You can see the list [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/). These extensions are implemented in Sizzle.

jQuery will use `querySelectorAll()` if it can, but reverts to Sizzle if necessary.

Comment: So those Sizzle extensions provide a syntax sugar to the native CSS selectors defined by the spec?

Comment: Yes. E.g. `:input` instead if `input, select, textarea`